# Can an installer be created to auto install a font on a Mac?

Tags: mac, fonts, fontconfig

I created a font which works equally well on Windows and Mac.  For Windows, I created an installer package;  when the user downloads the package and clicks on the .exe file it automatically installs the font to the Windows Fonts folder.
Can something similar be created for a Mac?
One associate has said he thought no, because SIP would block it.
But then I saw a forum from a few years ago that suggested it can be done using AppleScript and executed in C++ via the osascript command.
So can it be done? And if so, is there a tool that would help me create such a Mac executable?  Or a website I can go to that can assist me?  (I know some programming for Windows but really nothing for Mac).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an installer for fonts on Mac. You just double-click & it will launch Font Book & install/activate.

See [Apple KB - How to install and remove fonts on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT201749)